How can I monitor Glue jobs that are fired by EventBridge?
My stack is as follows:

EventBridge fires a Glue job at a regular interval.
Said Glue job runs Python scripts, which run as Step Functions.
The output of these scripts is saved to S3.

How can I monitor this? I ideally would like AWS (presumably, CloudWatch talking to SNS) to email me if the Glue job fails, but my definition of "fails" seems so broad that I feel like I'm solving the wrong problem. The below is a list of possible failures, but I'm hoping for a single solution that is so general that it hits all possibilities. If I could both always be alerted in case of a Glue error and make most possible failure cases trigger a Glue error, then I would probably be happy.

The Glue job simply doesn't fire.
The Glue job fires, but errors.
The Glue job fires, but the Step Functions do not.
The Step Functions error.


In the documentation there's examples of how to trigger events and they all start with something like:
exit 1 unless topic_exists?(
  Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1'),
  'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:aws-doc-sdk-examples-topic'
)

In POSIX, exit(1) is a signal that should be treated as error, and per the Elastic Bridge monitoring docs, you should be able to see the counters incrementing in case a rule exits with exit(1).
I think you have to first start all your rules with the exit 1 unless... construct for triggering rules. Then check if Cloudwatch increment the error counter.
I hope this helps.

This is more of a guess than an answer.
